# Can I make IntelliJ IDEA look more like Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, fonts, colors, intellij-idea

I've been developing in Eclipse for a long while, but am taking a hard look at IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.3 because of its good Flex development tools and Maven flexmojos integration.

But I just CAN'T STAND the look of the thing on Ubuntu 10.04.  Coming from Eclipse, the fonts and colors make everything very hard to read....very straining on the eyes.  I've played around with fonts and colors and now its a little bit better.

But has some kind soul already created some sort of profile I can load into IDEA and poof -- make it visually look more like Eclipse?

Comment: did you get any theme for the studio closer to eclipse?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Eclipse and IDEA are using different UI toolkits (SWT vs SWING), so it would be hard to make it look the same.

As @Shakedown said, changing Look&Feel in `Settings | Appearance` is one of the options. Note that Java allows to install additional third-party Look&Feels.

Editor font is configured in `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts`. Fonts are rendered by the JVM, so it shows any TTF fonts that it can find. If for some reason not all your system TTF fonts are visible, you need to copy *.ttf files into `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/fonts`. After restarting IDEA you'll be able to choose new fonts. Fonts missing some Unicode characters required for proper code display will not be listed.

Check out the [list of most popular programming fonts](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts). However, Java can render TTF fonts only and it may be hard to find TrueType versions of some fonts. My favorite font is Consolas (provided with Windows).

As for the color schemes, you can Google several contributed presets in the XML format, like [this one](http://gist.github.com/455778). Download the linked XML, rename it to `Cobalt.xml`, place the file in `~/.IntelliJIdea90/config/colors` directory. Restart IDEA, select Cobalt scheme in `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts`.

Another nice color scheme is [VibrantInk](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/download/attachments/4882442/vibrantInk.xml?version=1).

It's also possible to disable side tool window bars, menu bar, etc to make IDEA look like simple editor if you'd like so, even editor tabs can be completely hidden.

Comment: Very helpful.  A few comments: 1) Cobalt theme has light blue and medium blue text on a dark blue background -- honestly...i'd be blind in 4 hours!  2) VibrantInk is not bad, but I'll still probably hand-code one to match Eclipse.  3) I'll try to get some better fonts installed...thanks for the tips.  4) its really hard to get past how UGLY Swing applications are.

Comment: GTK L&F may be ugly on some distributions, on Windows the native Look&Feel is pretty descent.

Comment: Someone recently added this cool site for IDEA color schemes 
http://ideacolorschemes.com/shuffleschemeall

Answer (score 8):

#### Installation Eclipse color scheme:

1. Copy [`eclipse.xml`](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/576705/blog/src/eclipse.xml) to your IntelliJ IDEA preferences
   color directory. The directory varies, depending on which JetBrains IDE you are using. It
   is typically in:

   *Mac OS X*

   - `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/colors` (IntelliJ IDEA 13 Ultimate Edition)
   - `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC13/colors` (IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition),
   - `~/Library/Preferences/WebIDE70/colors` (PHPStorm 7.0).

   *Windows*

   - `%USERPROFILE%/.IdeaIC13/config/colors` (IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition)
2. Restart IntelliJ IDEA
3. Go to `Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts` and select one of the new
   color themes.

Comment: yes thats a bit less offensive! with IntelliJ CE 14 I had to delete the first line of the xml file else there was an error on startup. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

download a color scheme for IntelliJ such as "Classic Eclipse" [Editor's note: the website previously linked here has been replaced with spam and has been edited out]

It a jar file then you do `File > Import Settings...` and open the jar file and restart.

You should also go into `Preferences > Keymap` and change to the dropdown to be eclipse shortcuts so that you can get about easier.

Comment: That link is broken. Try this instead http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=935

Comment: Seems like that would make eclipse look like intellij, instead of the other way around

Answer (score 7):

If you are talking about the *dark side* of eclipse, you may like my **Eclipse Dark Color Scheme**:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11055-eclipse-dark-theme-color-scheme

Example:

[image]

If you want the same font like in Eclipse, use Consolas 13pt.

Comment: Thanks man ur a hero!  It might be worth pointing out that there are two of these similar plugins (In case you went directly on IntelliJ -> Plugins -> Marketplace).  I found "Eclipse - Dark Color Scheme"  and "Eclipse Dark Theme Color Scheme". I mistakenly installed the 1st one and disliked that it is too "zoomed out",
Hannes yours was just right!

Comment: @Top_Pug glad u like it :-) Consider leaving a good rating if it helped you.

Comment: Big thanks to you!
for IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 (Community Edition)
1. download pluin Eclipse Dark Theme Color Scheme
2. Switch to Darcula Theme
3. File->Settings...->Editor->Color Scheme:  Eclipse Dark Theme 
OK!

Answer (score 6):

I agree, I can't stand nearly all of the Look and Feels, but I really like Nimbus; `File -> Settings -> Appearance -> Look and Feel = Nimbus`. Give that a go and see if it helps.

Comment: That helped a lot with the colors...thanks.  I am also trying to fix/reset the Java syntax highlighting (what a pain).  The big issue at this point is the font.  Any way to add new fonts to IDEA?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

to your `idea64.vmoptions`

It improves antialiasing on my Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome Shell, Oracle JDK 7 slightly. It's not a big difference, still quite far from Eclipse, but it makes it better.

You can also try `on`, and `lcd` options instead of `gasp`. Some users report it makes a difference (for me, `on` and `gasp` seem to work the same, and `lcd` doesn't change anything).

I don't see any difference with Oracle JDK 8.

If you're using OpenJDK, you might need to patch it.

See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233#

**Update:**

For Oracle JDK 8, removing `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp` improves the rendering a bit for me on Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party. Here is something I found and worked for me. Basically it creates eclipse like syntax highlighting on intelliJ. Works for `Java` code and `XML` which is what I was looking for.

https://github.com/shalabh-jaiswal/eclipse-syntax-colors-for-intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

Why not install eclipse theme : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17004-eclipse-plus-theme

Answer (score -4):

1. Install Eclipse Color Theme Plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme
2. Download "IntelliJ Dracula" theme: http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=14105 (select the Eclipse Color Theme (XML) file download).
3. In Eclipse, go to Windows > Preferences > General > Appearances > Color Theme > Import a theme. And select the xml file just downloaded.

Comment: The OP was asking about IntelliJ not eclipse.