# intellij linux fonts

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

I am having an issue getting intellij to detect installed fonts on ubuntu 10.4.

The fonts are in ~.fonts and eclipse is able to detect them correctly and I restarted and stuff, so  I'm not sure what's going on here...

Thanks.

Comment: i don't know if this is any help, but when i looked at intellij and fonts i had the impression it just used java's mechanisms.  perhaps eclipse is doing something extra?  also, i believe font handling changed in java 7, so you might try that...

Comment: that's what this guy seems to indicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421045/can-i-make-intellij-idea-look-more-like-eclipse but even after I set up $JDK_HOME and added the fonts to where he said, it still wasn't working. I'm still on java 6 as a final note

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the fonts you are trying to use are Unicode and Monospace, as IDEA will not list other fonts by default. See also [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a recent openjdk it should mostly be able to access the same fonts as other apps (eclipse has an intrinsic advantage since it uses gtk, a native linux widget toolkit, via swt, and gtk knows where linux fonts are installed).

Native java UIs like intellij depend on how well the jvm is integrated with the system text stacks, which is not well at all for anything < java 1.7, since SUN used proprietaty text components long after their due date, in the name of stability, and because it was going broke and chose to ignore infrastructure problems that required time, money and energy to fix.