# TTF fonts not available on Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running Intellij 11.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.
I have installed some ttf fonts. My question is when I trying to change font under appearance, why I can see those fonts under eclipse, but not in Intellij?

Thank you.

Comment: With the IntelliJ platform I usually have to restart it to recognize any new fonts. But they do show properly after the restart. This in Re-Sharper and PHPStorm.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22448/not-all-ttf-fonts-visible-from-the-sun-jdk

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per [Can I make IntelliJ IDEA look more like Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421045/can-i-make-intellij-idea-look-more-like-eclipse)

> Fonts are rendered by the JVM, so it shows any TTF fonts that it can find. If for some reason not all your system TTF fonts are visible, you need to copy `*.ttf` files into `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/fonts`. After restarting IDEA you'll be able to choose new fonts. Fonts missing some Unicode characters required for proper code display will not be listed.