# Font UbuntuMono & Monaco doesn't appear in IntelliJ's dialog of choosing a font

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts

This question has been asked but the solution is not working for me. I went through the following similar questions:

1. [TTF fonts not available on Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734216/ttf-fonts-not-available-on-intellij)
2. [A font doesn't appear in IntelliJ's dialog of choosing a font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222833/a-font-doesnt-appear-in-intellijs-dialog-of-choosing-a-font)

My question is basically the same. I have UbuntuMono and Monaco (installed using [this](https://gist.github.com/rogerleite/99819)) properly installed but the fonts are not loading in the intellij font dialog

I am using intellij 2017 on Ubuntu 14.04

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the Similar Issue. Solved it by using different types of TTF files of Monaco fonts. You can find it here.

```
https://github.com/1mandev/Monaco-IDE-font
```