# Change foreground color of “Parameter Info” in IntelliJ Editor

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

How to change the foreground color of "Parameter Info" in IntelliJ (when you press : "ctrl + P" on method parameters)?

There is nothing in : FILE | SETTINGS | COLORS & FONT

Comment: maybe reated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421045/can-i-make-intellij-idea-look-more-like-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change it righ now without changing the Look&Feel, see the related issues:

- [IDEA-95904](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95904) Darcula parameter info pop-up colors hard to read
- [IDEA-95873](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95873) Darcula: Parameter Info popup is unreadable