# Is there any way to customize Android Studio's look-and-feel/fonts everything into eclipse style?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, customization

Is there any way to customize Android Studio's look-and-feel/fonts everything into eclipse style?
Apparently android community is deprecating eclipse and use android studio instead. But as a long time eclipse users, I like the look-and-feel of eclipse much much better than android studio

I am using **Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ so take a look at this guide on how to change the font and colors:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html

Here is a similar question:
[Can I make IntelliJ IDEA look more like Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421045/can-i-make-intellij-idea-look-more-like-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks! That looks exactly what I need, I just feel everything in AndroidStudio so hard to read